# Roblox Studio ignoring my "If Statement" line

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have a script that is on repeat, constantly checking a value. However, even if the value is true, the function won't even run at all.

I tried adding "wait()" to solve the problem but that didn't work at all.

```
useless = 0
wait(1)
repeat
    print("watno")
    wait()
    if script.Parent.Parent.Parent.windowsopen.Value == true then
        wait()
        for i = 5.5,0,0.1 do
            print("wat")
            wait()
            useless = useless + i
            script.Parent.Size = Vector3.new(script.Parent.Size.X, script.Parent.Y - 0.1, script.Parent.Size.Z )

        end
    elseif script.Parent.Parent.Parent.windowsopen.Value == false then

        wait()
    end
until false
```

The "windowsopen" value is always true, but it never runs it.

Comment: Have you tried without the `== true`? and have you checked the type of `Value`, you can do that by using `type(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.windowsopen.Value)` and printing the result.

Comment: The step in your for loop looks to be incrementing - while the end condition is smaller than 5.5.

Comment: Why would randomly adding `wait()` solve the problem?!

Answer (score 0):

problem you have most likely caused by your `for` loop, you should change it to

```
      for i = 55, 0, -1 do
            print("wait")
            wait()
            useless = useless + 0.1*i
            script.Parent.Size = Vector3.new(script.Parent.Size.X, script.Parent.Y - 0.1, script.Parent.Size.Z )
        end
```

because (a) if you want to decrease `i` in loop third parameter should be negative , (b) you really should not use `float` or `double` in `for` loop because of precision\representation: 0.1 may end up represented as 0.1000000000000001 (or something like that) and in i will end up never be equal to zero in loop. For more info check what format lua uses for representing `double` (i think it is IEEE 754 but i may be wrong)  also you can look at https://floating-point-gui.de/